# Convert dictionary values from list to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function which results

```
dict1 = {'2132': [{'L': {'Y': '452.2'}}, {'L': {'N': '21'}}], '2345': [{'L': {'Y': '87'}}, {'C': {'N': '56'}}, {'6': {'Y': '45.23'}}]
```

I have another function i need to pass 2132,L,Y values from dict1 as an arguments and it should result 452.2

```
def getx(a, b, c):
    try:
        return dict1[a][b][c]
    except:
        return None
```

when i give `dict1['2132']` which results `[{'L': {'Y': '452.2'}}, {'L': {'N': '21'}}]`

i want `dict1['2132']['L']['Y']` should result as `452.2`

so i need my dictionary

```
dict1 = {'2132': [{'L': {'Y': '452.2'}}, {'L': {'N': '21'}}], '2345': [{'L': {'Y': '87'}}, {'C': {'N': '56'}}, {'6': {'Y': '45.23'}}]
```

to show as

```
dict1 = {'2132': {{'L': {'Y': '452.2'}}, {'L': {'N': '21'}}}, '2345': {{'L': {'Y': '87'}}, {'C': {'N': '56'}}, {'6': {'Y': '45.23'}}}
```

OR is there any other way that we can pull the 4th value when the dict1 is

```
dict1 = {'2132': [{'L': {'Y': '452.2'}}, {'L': {'N': '21'}}], '2345': [{'L': {'Y': '87'}}, {'C': {'N': '56'}}, {'6': {'Y': '45.23'}}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your solution

```
#v1='2132' v2='L' v3='Y'
def Solution(v1,v2,v3):
    if v1 in dict1.keys():
        for i in dict1[v1]:
            if v2 in i.keys():
                if v3 in i[v2]:
                    return i[v2][v3]
    return None

dict1 = {'2132': [{'L': {'Y': '452.2'}}, {'C': {'N': '21'}}], '2345': [{'L': {'Y': '87'}}, {'C': {'N': '56'}},{'6': {'Y': '45.23'}}]}
print(Solution('2132','L','Y'))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
for key,values in dict1.items():
    temp_dict = defaultdict(dict)
    for val in values: #values is a list of dict
        for k,v in val.items():
            temp_dict[k].update(v)
    dict1[key] = dict(temp_dict)
print(dict1)
#{'2132': {'L': {'Y': '452.2', 'N': '21'}}, '2345': {'L': {'Y': '87'}, 'C': {'N': '56'}, '6': {'Y': '45.23'}}}
```

And then

```
def getx(a, b, c):
    try:
        return dict1[a][b][c]
    except:
        return None
print(getx('2132','L','Y'))
#452.2
```